# php load database side-by-side

Tags: php, layout

```
<?php
        try {

            $stmt = $db->query('SELECT postID, postTitle, postDesc, postDate FROM blog_posts ORDER BY postID DESC');
            while($row = $stmt->fetch()){

                echo '<div>';
                    echo '<h1><a href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'].'">'.$row['postTitle'].'</a></h1>';
                    echo '<p>Posted on '.date('jS M Y H:i:s', strtotime($row['postDate'])).'</p>';
                    echo '<p>'.$row['postDesc'].'</p>';             
                    echo '<p><a href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'].'">Read More</a></p>';               
                echo '</div>';

            }

        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    ?>
```

This code loads the data by rows. I need to load the data side by side.

Comment: side by side ??  you mean to say column by column??

Comment: Side-by-side only reminds me term of refrigerators...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague, you do not say what your actual issue is. You current solution explicitly generates markup such that details you visualized are placed in paragraph elements. Paragraph elements obviously get visualized vertically below each other.

If your issue really just is that you want to have the details aligned horizontally next to each other, then you have several approaches you can try:

**First approach:**

you can simply modify your style sheet rules (css) to display paragraph elements accordingly:

```
p {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

*However that is considered ugly, since it breaks the semantic meaning of a paragraph...*

**Second approach:**

You can simply change how you create your markup to something like that:

```
echo '<div>';
echo '<h1><a href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'].'">'.$row['postTitle'].'</a></h1>';
echo '<div class="cell">Posted on '.date('jS M Y H:i:s', strtotime($row['postDate'])).'</div>';
echo '<div class="cell">'.$row['postDesc'].'</div>';             
echo '<div class="cell"><a href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'].'">Read More</a></div>';               
echo '</div>';
```

Then add such a css rule to your style sheet definition:

```
div.cell {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

*This is considered the clean and correct approach.*

**Third approach:**

Similar to the second approach you can place the details inside table cells, so create a table structure to hold the data. This is very reliable, but it is considered a bit of a miss usage of tables for layouting... It also creates issues in the area of "barrier reduction" which is getting a more and more important aspect of todays web page design and usability thoughts. Also it does not allow the layout to adapt to different screen widths in a responsive manner, so you will run into layout problems with different devices like smartphones and tables.

*So I would recommend against this approach.*

---

**Edit:** 
OK, seems like this was all for nothing, because the question was, as remarked initially, vague. A typical example of much effort for nothing because of a question lacking precision...

So according to your comment here you want the *outer* `div`s to be aligned side by side.

Actually I already gave the answer above, but I can certainly repeat it here in a precise manner that matches what you ask in the comment:

Just clearly mark the containers to receive special alignment by adding a class:

```
echo '<div class="outer">';
echo '<h1><a href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'].'">'.$row['postTitle'].'</a></h1>';
echo '<p>Posted on '.date('jS M Y H:i:s', strtotime($row['postDate'])).'</p>';
echo '<p>'.$row['postDesc'].'</p>';             
echo '<p><a href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'].'">Read More</a></p>';               
echo '</div>';
```

Then add a style rule for that:

```
div.outer {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

I created a `fiddle` demonstrating the effect:
https://jsfiddle.net/oLrugrLn/

Comment: what was I meant is, load  each div side by side, not the para inside the div.

Comment: @kishon See why it is important to write _precise_ questions?

Comment: @kishon I added a section to the answer that uses the same idea as in the second approach to align the _outer_ `div`'s side by side.

Comment: Glad I could be of help :-) Give something back one day!

Comment: how to add a black boarder round each outer div?

Comment: @kishon Hm, doesn't the green border the fiddle I created for you show how to do that? I suggest you start reading an introduction to css rules...

Comment: how to set to display 4 columns in a row? rest must go to the 2nd, 3rd,... columns.

Comment: Sorry, but you are miss using this site... I wrote above: "I suggest you start reading an introduction to css rules..." I meant that. You are expected to be able to read documentations and learn from them. Simply asking others to do your work for you is considered impolite here. If you really did what you were asked and still cannot find an answer yourself, then please open a new question. Thanks!